# Find total number of objects and number of moving object from camera/video file in iOS through OpenCV library

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, object-detection, motion-detection

Currently I am working on iOS project that needs total number of ellipse object from camera/video file and which ellipse objects are moving in that video. I am using OpenCV library to find out ellipse object but I am new to OpenCV so please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What research have you done, and how did it help/not help you? Did you look at this thread (first result for "opencv detect moving object" at Google) : http://answers.opencv.org/question/14899/motion-detection-with-opencv-c/ ?

Comment: I am following CvVideoCamera for tracking object and implemented its delegate “- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image” and get 30 frames per second but I don’t know how to get all ellipse object count and also moving objects count through this method so please let me help to find out these 2 types  counts.